# Why is the border width of a range xlThin if it has no border

Tags: excel, vba

I have this peculiar problem that cells without borders have the border values shown in VBA watch window as `xlThin` (numeric value `2`).

I wrote a script to change border `xlThin` to `xlMedium` and it changed every border in the range. I then selected the entire sheet, clicked "clear all", and ran the script again. Same thing. I opened a new sheet, unchecked "Show Gridlines" and got a blank page. I then ran the script. Same thing.

There is absolutely no border in the cells in the range but VBA thinks the borders are all `xlThin`.

Google search turned up nothing. Do I need to reinstall Office? This is Office 2010 on Windows 10 19041.867.

[Edit] OK. Forget about `xlNone`.
Please look at the attached screendump. Notice that B2 has no border but in the Watch window, `Range("B2").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight` is `2`. This is the only sheet. There is no other sheet.

[image]

Comment: `and ran the script again....` Please share the script.

Comment: There is no `xlNone` for `Borders.Weight` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlborderweight

Comment: The values are xlHairline = 1 , xlThin = 2, xlMedium = -4138 and xlThick = 4

Comment: I would have thought that if you clear the formats, then the default cell style will be adopted. This default style will most likely be set to `xlThin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the comments according to the [XlBorderWeight enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlborderweight) there is no `xlNone` for `Borders.Weight`.

Acoording to the [Borders.LineStyle property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.borders.linestyle) a cell with no border has

```
Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
```

Actually the weight of the border has nothing to do wether it exists or not. This is defined by the `LineStyle` of the border.

This is actually a clever design, because this way you can have an invisible border (with a line style: none) that still has a weight.